# metodos de ordenamiento

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Son dos métodos de ordenamiento que se ejecutan en secuencia, el problema es que el segundo en ejecutarse encuentra el array a trabajar ya ordenado, no entiendo como se modifica la variable que contiene los datos:

```
   const ordenamientoPorInsercion = (datos) => {
      console.time();
      let i, j;
      let auxiliar, actual, movimientos = 0;
      let length = datos.length;

      for (i = 1; i < length; i += 1) {
        actual = datos[i];
        for (j = i; j > 0; j -= 1) {
          if (actual < datos[j-1]) {
            auxiliar = datos[j-1];
            datos[j-1] = datos[j];
            datos[j] = auxiliar;
            movimientos += 1;
          }
        } 
      }
      console.timeEnd();
      return mensaje(movimientos, 'ordenamiento por insercion');
    }

    const ordenamientoDeBurbuja = (datos) => {
      console.time();
      let i;
      let auxiliar, intercambio = 0,  movimientos = 0;
      let length = datos.length;

      do {
        intercambio = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < length; i += 1) {
          if (datos[i] > datos[i + 1]) {
            auxiliar = datos[i];
            datos[i] = datos[i + 1];
            datos[i + 1] = auxiliar;
            intercambio+=1;
            movimientos+=1;
          }

        }    
      } while (!intercambio == 0);

      console.timeEnd();
      return mensaje(movimientos, 'ordenamiento de burbuja');
    }


     const ordenarArrayNombres = () => {
      const arrayNombres = data.split('\r\n');              
      console.log(ordenamientoPorInsercion(arrayNombres));
      console.log(ordenamientoDeBurbuja(arrayNombres));
     }
        ordenarArrayNombres();
      }
    })
```

En mi repositorio esta el archivo completo y el arhchivo de lectura. https://github.com/Mooenz/Portafolio-Javascript.

En caso de no ser explicito, por favor me lo hacen saber.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript es interpretado, lo cual quiere decir que se ejecuta línea por línea, tu ordenas el arreglo con la primera función, y una vez ordenado, ese mismo arreglo, se lo pasas a la segunda función ya ordenado

Puede crear dos arreglos iguales y pasárselos a las diferentes funciones

Comment: Sería mejor si agregas un ejemplo :)